# DevExtreme controls not initialized error randomly in document.ready and body.onload event

Tags: jquery, web-applications, devexpress, devextreme

We have a web application developed using `.NET Core 2.2` and `DevExtreme 19.1`.
We are accessing the devextreme controls in the page ready event (documet.ready event) to do some business logic.

When we tried to access the devextreme control instance in the `document.ready` and `body.onload event`, randomly we get `control not initialized` error.

We have [ASPxClientGlobalEvents.ControlsInitialized Event](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientGlobalEvents.ControlsInitialized) which triggers when all the controls are initialized for `DevExpress ASP.NET controls`.

Is there any way to check whether all the devextreme controls are initialized in a page using `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

The DevExtreme JQuery equivalent is [onInitialized](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onInitialized)

You cannot access widget elements in this function because it is executed before they are ready. So depending on your requirement you may want to use [onContentReady](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onContentReady)